# SQL multiple conditional sum complexity

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple sums I need to calculate for one group of data, with different WHERE conditions.

I can do it in one of two ways:

Multiple sub-queries.

1. (SELECT SUM(A) FROM B WHERE C>0 AND D=6 GROUP BY id) as sum_a,
2. (SELECT SUM(A) FROM B WHERE C<0 AND D=6 GROUP BY id) as sum_b,
3. ......... And 6 more

Or I can do it this way, using JOIN and conditional SUMs:

1. LEFT JOIN (SELECT
2. SUM(IIF(C>0 AND D=6, A, 0)) as sum_a,
3. SUM(IIF(C<0 AND D=6, A, 0)) as sum_a,
4. ......... And 6 more
5. FROM B GROUP BY id)
6. as table
7. ON table.id = main.id

If all of the conditions are indexed, (on a 14,000,000 rows table), which way is faster?

Comment: Do alternative 2, conditional sum's.

Comment: likely 2. is the way to go, but you don't show the larger context of the query for 1. and the group by makes me think you weren't doing it in a way that would work anyway.  if you want good advice here, it really helps to show complete runnable queries.

Comment: @Amit it is impossible to tell which query is faster without having full text of the query, and some data - execution plan and profiler data, please provide this information - let me know if you need help on how to gather it.